# android and ios communacation

Tags: java, android, ios

I was wondering if i can pass objects between ios and android.

I am using command Design pattern in order to pass different commands between 2 android smartphones.
I am now interesting in how to involve the ios platform in order to communicate with iphone smartphones

Is JSON can help me?

Answer (score 2):

I will admit I do not know much about "command Design pattern". Here my two cents.

You cannot pass *objects* between two different languages. Objects are only created in memory during Runtime in many different ways depending on the language.
You can how ever serialize your objects into text (json) and then de-serialize in another language to the same **model** of the object. So for example, let say your object is in c#

```
public class Person
{
    String firstName { get; set; }

    public Person(String name)
    {
        this.firstName = name;
    }

}
```

JSON could do only this for you

> ```
> {"Person": [{"Name": "Richard"}]}
> ```

Notice how that the json only keeps data structure of object? If you have function that call other function or does some kind of calculation, json won't be able to do that. But all is not lost! What you can do is pass an json *message* object, that once parsed your code can detect and ACT depending on the message.

A sample json message could be

```
{"REPLY": [{"Response" : "OK"}]}
```

Then in iOS or java, you parse it and then you do if statement check (IF OK, THEN.... ELSE...).

So in short, you cant pass objects directly between different languages. You can pass data structures. This data structure can help pass message to ios or java or window 7 which you can implement to do whatever you need it to do. Hope this help....?!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization

API to convert java to json
http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/